# CSS div with dynamic height to responsive background image

Tags: html, css, image, dynamic

I trying to create a class with a dynamic image background on bootstrap3 without success. Instead use height equal to 180px i trying to use 100% to make it responsive. Whats wrong?

```css
.audio-cover {
 background: url("http://media.merchantcircle.com/22662073/180px-Smiley_svg_full.png");
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 100%; //instead use 180px
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 audio-cover"></div>
```

Comment: In responsive web design, you need to make `width` or `max-width` of images `100%` and allow the height grow up, if you need to control the height, you need to use some `wrapper` and set the height for that and use `overflow:hidden`

Comment: why do you not use `img` inside `div`?

Comment: in order to see height:100%; working , audio-cover's parent needs an height in css specified and valid, else it is 100% of null

Comment: @MehdiDehghani i've a warp div with overflow:hidden; height: 176px;– even so doesn't work. and audio-cover with width:100%

Comment: warp was the solution, but i'm trying to create a div with a dynamic height. so i don't want to use 180px on my warp. how can i do that?

Comment: @8lou pls can you mark my answer as accepted by checking the tick beside the answer? thanks

Answer (score 4):

set your `background-size` to `cover` and specify a `min-height`.

check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndz2d4f9/)

Answer (score 3):

there are a few ways to make an image responsive, but there are questions, do you want to keep the aspect ratio?

if you want to keep your approach of using a div and assigning background properties you can use the following css:

```
#image {
    background-image: url(http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

this will make the div 100% height and width of the parent, but the image background-size is 100% width with auto height. This means, the height will keep its aspect ratio of the original image.

if you want the image to take the full height-width of the parent and not maintain its aspect ratio you can change background-size to:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

you can play around with it here http://jsfiddle.net/1f36wedc/

Answer (score 0):

The responsive idea for images is like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="SOME_WHERE" />
</div>

div{
    width: X; // depended on your logic
    height: 170px;
    overflow: hidden; // by this one, maybe you lost some part of image, but is okay
}
div > img{
    max-width: 100%;  
}
```

Hope this help